How do i create a page-sequence for each image in a directory in Apache FOP
Suppose i have a directory with n images. I would like to add one image per page.
For example :
In a directory called "Images", i have the below 2 images:
newpage0.jpg and newpage1.jpg
I would like to map each image on a single page. How do i dynamically create page-sequences for the number of images present in the directory?
The below code works fine for one image.
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
             <fo:block>
                 <fo:external-graphic src="url(Images/newpage0.jpg)" width="100%"
                  scaling="uniform" content-width="scale-to-fit" />
             </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>

Please help.

Why XSLT 2, given that current language version is 3.0 and has been that since 2017? Anyway, XSLT 3/XPath 3.1 has a function uri-collection which, with some processor specific query parameters, should allow you to select e.g. uri-collection('Images/?select=*.jpg') to have a sequence of collection of jpg files in that directory and then you can use any construct you know or like in XSLT 3 (xsl:apply-templates select="uri-collection('Images/?select=*.jpg'), xsl:for-each select="uri-collection('Images/?select=*.jpg')", xsl:iterate select="uri-collection('Images/?select=*.jpg')").

To allow you mark your question as solved, I post my comment as an answer.
The current version of XSLT is 3.0, and has been that since 2017. In the Java world where you use Apache FOP you can easily use XSLT 3.0 with the current version 12(.4) of Saxon HE, available on Github and Maven.
In XSLT 3.0 there is the XPath 3.1 function uri-collection that, with some vendor specific extension, for Saxon allows you  to select e.g. uri-collection('Images/?select=*.jpg') to have a sequence of collection URIs of jpg files in that directory and then you can use any construct you know or like in XSLT 3 (xsl:apply-templates select="uri-collection('Images/?select=*.jpg'), xsl:for-each select="uri-collection('Images/?select=*.jpg')", xsl:iterate select="uri-collection('Images/?select=*.jpg')") to process the sequence and output a fo:page-sequence for each item in the sequence.
